# Lisp type system trouble

Tags: types, lisp, system

I am doing some homework and I am confused on some things regarding lisp

**Question:**

Consider the Lisp statement:

```
(eval (read-from-string (read-line)))
```

Very briefly describe the features of Lisp’s type system that are required to support this type of statement.

**Thoughts**

I am very new to Lisp so I am unsure on how to even approach the question.
I understand type system is basically the rules of the language  of how it works and what it can do. I just don't know how to describe features of Lisp with this one line of code.

Comment: what implimentation you are talking about?

Comment: @coredump I don't believe I'm told of a certain implementation.

Comment: I don't think you can say anything about the type system based on so little information. Eg. Haskell has static typing and similar code could easily look the same since the typing also can be inferred.

Comment: @Sylwester Is that so? What static type does Haskell logic assign to the expression `(read-from-string (read-line))`? Remember, the input can be anything: an expression like `(+ 2  2)`, an integer token, a string literal, and so on: the type has to mirror that.

Comment: @Kaz `read-line` might return string (probably not since it's side efffetcs), `read-from-string` might return syntax objects or something that `eval` would be glad to do something with but would be totally useless as a value. Eg. `(read-from-string "2")` might not become the same value as evaluating `2`.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a homework question, I will not answer it for you. Instead, I try to help you to ask yourself the right questions.

Whenever there's a concept in a question that you don't know or understand yet, then you should try to understand *that* first.

> I understand type system is basically the rules of the language of how it works and what it can do.

Take a step back and think about *what* this sentence is telling about your understanding of "type system". **Do you understand what a type system is?** I don't think so. **Do you understand the purpose of a type system?** I don't think so.

So, try to answer these questions first. (That's a quick jump to Wikipedia) In order to verify your understand, try to answer these questions:

- What's the difference between dynamic and static typing?
- What's the difference between strong and weak typing?
- If `42` has the type `Integer`, and some function `foo` takes a single parameter of type `Integer` and returns a `String`, what is the type of the expression `(foo 42)` (calling the function)?
- If `"OMG"` has the type `String`, and some function `foo` takes a single parameter of type `Integer` and returns a `String`, what is the type of the expression `(foo "OMG")`?

Try to answer the last two questions not only for Lisp, but also for some other languages (like Java, C, C++, Haskell; adjusting the call syntax of course).

Now, try to think of the type of (keeping to Common Lisp `eval` here):

```
(eval '(+ 1 2))
```

And finally, what is the type of:

```
(eval (read))
```

Comment: So from further research Lisp is strongly typed and dynamic, correct? This is because variables are interpreted at run time and also because you have to translate strings and numbers depending on what you are doing. So, looking at: **(eval (read-from-string (read-line)))** , we can say that it is strongly typed because we are using **read-from-string** and **eval** shows us that variables are interpreted at run time. Does this seem about right?